# Why does the spark-cassandra-connector sometimes return incorrect data for date column?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I faced with issues, the Cassandra Connector in java may return incorrect values for date column in Cassandra. If I reload the app, everything fine. I don't know why it happens and how can I fix it

[image]

As you can see it return address of object, but not the value.

Comment: how many nodes in the cluster?

Comment: @AlexOtt Cassandra cluster has 3 nodes

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need to perform a [repair](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/repair.html) because your data is out of sync.  Spark Cassandra Connector reads data using the `LOCAL_ONE` consistency level, so when it reach the node that contains outdated data, then it reads the stale data.

Comment: I was using multiple host name for connector. Like host0,host1,host2.
I've just change it just to host0 and now it works. 
Thank you, your answer very helped me.

Comment: host that you specify in the connection is just for the initial connection to a cluster. After connection is established, connector discovers all nodes in the given data center, and use them. So result is the same for you if you specify one node or three nodes